# How correct add EditText to Fragment programmatically?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-edittext

This is My **Java** code:

```
View RV2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__dummy,container, false);
LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) RV2 .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
EditText ET = new EditText(getActiity());
ET.setText("LOL");
ET.setId(5);
ET.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LL.addView(ET);
return RV;
```

Thus not lit **red** line, the **application is stopped**, when I run.

Thank You!

Comment: What does the stack trace say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
View RV2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__dummy,container, false);
LinearLayout LL = (LinearLayout) RV2 .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
EditText ET = new EditText(getActiity());
ET.setText("LOL");
ET.setId(5);
ET.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
LL.addView(ET);

((ViewGroup)RV2).addView(LL);

return RV2;
```

please have a try.

Answer (score 1):

You are inflating the layout in `RV2` and returning `RV`

Change

```
return RV;
```

to

```
return RV2;
```

You have to return the `View` in which you are inflating the layout

Comment: `RV` and also that `RV2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way it will work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/family_detail_linear"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        ></LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/family_detail_addbutton"
        android:text="Add More"
        />

</LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Java Code

```
public class MyFrag extends Fragment{


    private Button addmoremember;
    private Activity activity;
    private LinearLayout layout;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.family_details, container, false);

        activity=getActivity();
        addmoremember=(Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.family_detail_addbutton);
        layout=(LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.family_detail_linear);
       addmoremember.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                EditText edttexname= new EditText(activity);
                edttexname.setHint("Enter Name");

                layout.addView(edttexname);

            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```